# Pytest code coverage for if __name__ == '__main__'

Tags: python, pytest

I'm trying to get 100% code coverage with pytest-cov and I'm just missing the lines 245-248 according to this.

server.py, 97%, 245-248

Here are the relevant lines in server.py:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with app.app_context(): 
        db.drop_all() # Drop all existing tables in the database
        db.create_all() # Create new tables in the database
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

testing.py:

```
import tempfile
import os
import pytest
import server
import time

# Set up client
@pytest.fixture
def client():
    db_fd, name = tempfile.mkstemp() # Creates and opens a temporary file

    server.app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///'+str(name)
    server.app.config['TESTING'] = True
    with server.app.test_client() as client:
        with server.app.app_context():
            server.db.drop_all() # Clear database between test functions
            server.db.create_all() # Create new database
        yield client

    # Test is over, close and remove the temporary file
    os.close(db_fd) # Tear down 
    os.unlink(name) # Unlink

def test_server(client):

    with server.app.app_context():
        server.db.drop_all()
        server.db.create_all()
        with server.db.session.begin():
            server.db.session.add(server.User(username='testuser'))
        result = server.db.session.query(server.User).filter_by(username='testuser').first()
        assert result is not None
        assert isinstance(result, server.User)
```

It passed but it's not covering the test case. What do I need to change to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are worried that the code inside `if __name__ == '__main__':` is not getting tested, which would be a valid concern, then I would strongly suggest to move it out into a function that could be tested, so that you end up only with something like:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If **after that** you are still not happy that you don't have 100% coverage, then I'm afraid that **what you are chasing is a bit of a fallacy**. However, you could then exclude all such blocks from your reports.

*.coveragerc*:

```ini
[report]

exclude_lines =
    if __name__\s*==\s*['"]__main__['"]\s*:
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `# pragma: no cover` in the lines you want to exclude:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':  # pragma: no cover
    with app.app_context(): 
        db.drop_all() # Drop all existing tables in the database
        db.create_all() # Create new tables in the database
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```